# Microsoft`s Face Api with PHP

Tags: php, api, curl, face-recognition

When I try to detect the face and its attributes from an image using CURL request to microsoft`s projectoxford it always return the following error code

{"code":"BadArgument","message":"Invalid Media Type."}.

While testing the face detection using their test console, it successfully returns the face attributes from the particular image.Here is my code

```
$query_params = array('analyzesFaceLandmarks' => 'true',
                     'analyzesAge' => 'true',
                     'analyzesGender' => 'true',
                     'analyzesHeadPose' => 'true',
                     'subscription-key'=> 'my subscription key'
);
$params = "";
$sep    = '';
foreach ($query_params as $key => $value) {
   $params .= $sep.$key.'='.$value;
   $sep     = '&';
}


$API_Endpoint = "https://api.projectoxford.ai/face/v0/detections?".$params;
$img_arr      = array('url'=>'{remote file path}');
$data         = json_encode($img_arr);

$headers = array();
         $headers[] = 'Content-Type:application/json';
         $headers[] = 'Content-Length:'.strlen($data);
         $ch = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);


         curl_close($ch);
         print_r('<pre>');
         print_r($result);
```

If anybody know the reason for this problem,please help me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but here is a modified working example.  I think the issue you were having is it's CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER - not CURLOPT_HEADER (in this case).

```
define( 'API_BASE_URL',     'https://api.projectoxford.ai/face/v0/detections?' );
define( 'API_PRIMARY_KEY',      'YOUR KEY HERE' );
$img = 'YOUR IMAGE URL HERE';

$post_string = '{"url":"' . $img . '"}';

$query_params = array(
    'analyzesFaceLandmarks'     => 'true',
    'analyzesAge'                       => 'true',
    'analyzesGender'                    => 'true',
    'analyzesHeadPose'              => 'true',
);

$params = '';
foreach( $query_params as $key => $value ) {
    $params .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
}
$params .= 'subscription-key=' . API_PRIMARY_KEY;

$post_url = API_BASE_URL . $params;

$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($post_string))
    );    

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    $response = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );

print_r( '<pre>' );
print_r( $response );
```